# How do I attribute a Campaign to a Lead using visual workflow?

Tags: leads, visual-workflow, flow, campaign, visual-flows

I have a publicly accessible flow and it has been working great. As an adjustment, we would like to hard code a campaign for each lead created by this flow. However, updating the campaign field from a Record Create - Lead inside a visual workflow is not allowed... It's not even available for selection. See screen shot...

[image]

How can we attribute this new lead, being created in the flow, to an existing campaign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgo the standard create operation as this will not meet your need.  Instead create an apex class which will be called from your flow.  You will need to pass the parameters from the flow into the apex class.

see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_apex.htm

and this link on how to pass parameters
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_plugin_using.htm